# Опять об оформлении диалогов.

Tags: диалог

Сегодня натолкнулся на оригинал романа, виденного мной прежде лишь в переводе на русский. Меня удивило, что у нас диалоги передавались при помощи длинного тире, в то время как в английском оригинале использовались кавычки. И тут я поймал себя на мысли, что никогда не видел текста на английском, содержащей диалоги, оформленные при помощи тире.

Действительно ли такое оформление применяется только у нас или я заблуждаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, в английском языке действительно диалоги не принято оформлять с помощью тире. Однако в русских изданиях в английских диалогах все же встречается тире. Не знаю, исходя из чего они ставят тире, но по правилам тире не нужно.